# Meteor and Phaser - error with simple sample

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, phaser-framework

I have been running Meteor application as well as Phaser applications standalone and everything is fine. However, when I try to run a Phaser game with Meteor I get errors.

So, one question is if anyone runs successfully Phaser together with Meteor.

The other question/issue is more specific. I run the following:

- ubuntu 14.04
- Meteor 1.1.0.2
- Phaser v2.3.0

My directory contains:

- app.js
- index.html
- phaser.js

app.js:

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
        Template.game.game = function(){
        var game = new Phaser.Game(320,320, Phaser.AUTO, 'firstGame', { preload: preload, create: create, update:update });
        }

        function preload(){
        }

        function create(){
        }

        function update(){
        }
    }

    if (Meteor.isServer) {
    };
    }
```

index.html:

```
    <body>
      {{> game}}
    </body>

    <template name="game">
      {{game}}
    </template>
```

The error when I run meteor is:

```
cmt@ubuntu:~/projects/myMeteorProjects/issueReplication1$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/projects/myMeteorProjects/issueReplication1 ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
W20150728-21:54:46.964(-4)? (STDERR)          
W20150728-21:54:46.966(-4)? (STDERR) /home/cmt/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150728-21:54:46.966(-4)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150728-21:54:46.967(-4)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150728-21:54:46.967(-4)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: document is not defined
W20150728-21:54:46.967(-4)? (STDERR)     at root (app/phaser.js:2546:34)
W20150728-21:54:46.967(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/phaser.js:12437:4
W20150728-21:54:46.967(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/phaser.js:88287:3
W20150728-21:54:46.967(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/cmt/projects/myMeteorProjects/issueReplication1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150728-21:54:46.967(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150728-21:54:46.968(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/cmt/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150728-21:54:46.968(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/cmt/projects/myMeteorProjects/issueReplication1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20150728-21:54:51.718(-4)? (STDERR)          
W20150728-21:54:51.719(-4)? (STDERR) /home/cmt/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150728-21:54:51.719(-4)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150728-21:54:51.719(-4)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150728-21:54:51.730(-4)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: document is not defined
W20150728-21:54:51.730(-4)? (STDERR)     at root (app/phaser.js:2546:34)
W20150728-21:54:51.730(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/phaser.js:12437:4
W20150728-21:54:51.730(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/phaser.js:88287:3
W20150728-21:54:51.730(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/cmt/projects/myMeteorProjects/issueReplication1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150728-21:54:51.731(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150728-21:54:51.731(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/cmt/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150728-21:54:51.731(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/cmt/projects/myMeteorProjects/issueReplication1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20150728-21:54:56.477(-4)? (STDERR)          
W20150728-21:54:56.478(-4)? (STDERR) /home/cmt/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150728-21:54:56.479(-4)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150728-21:54:56.480(-4)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150728-21:54:56.490(-4)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: document is not defined
W20150728-21:54:56.490(-4)? (STDERR)     at root (app/phaser.js:2546:34)
W20150728-21:54:56.491(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/phaser.js:12437:4
W20150728-21:54:56.491(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/phaser.js:88287:3
W20150728-21:54:56.491(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/cmt/projects/myMeteorProjects/issueReplication1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150728-21:54:56.492(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150728-21:54:56.492(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/cmt/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
W20150728-21:54:56.492(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/cmt/projects/myMeteorProjects/issueReplication1/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try putting your phaser.js into the client folder.

See the meteor docs on file structuring: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

What I believe is happening is phaser.js is trying to access the document, which does not exist in node (the server side). The document is only client side.

Furthermore, it would probably be good practice to just keep it in the client folder since it is something you only want to run on the client.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. It resolved my issue and going forward I will always follow the suggested directory structure :-).

Comment: Hi cap_mkt_tools! Could you upload you skeleton folder to git hub ? It would be great. I'm currently unable to get phaser running on Meteor. :)

Comment: Sure @DavidPanart. It's on capitalmarkettools/pressIt.git. Let me know if you need any instructions.